# Laravel 7 Fonts And Owl Carousel

Tags: css, fonts, carousel, laravel-7

I wanted to change the font of my Laravel website, so I used `@font-face` in the `style.css` file and added the sources to the font; so this is my css code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Adlanta';
  font-style: 'normal';
  font-weight: '700';
  src: url('../webfonts/Adlanta/regular/Adlanta.eot');
  src: url('../webfonts/Adlanta/regular/Adlanta.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../webfonts/Adlanta/regular/Adlanta.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../webfonts/Adlanta/regular/Adlanta.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../webfonts/Adlanta/regular/Adlanta.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../webfonts/Adlanta/regular/Adlanta.svg#Adlanta') format('svg');
}

body {
     color: #666666;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-family: 'Adlanta', sans-serif;
     line-height: 1.80857;
}
```

Here is the picture of the files Which I converted from `.otf` file on this site: [Converter site](https://cloudconvert.com/otf-to-eot): [image: Files]

**Before adding this css code I had this carousel that gets images from instagram: [image: Correct View]**

```
<?php
    try {
        $media = App\Traits\Instagram::feed();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //
    }

?>
@isset($media)
@if(count($media) > 0)
<!-- Start Instagram Feed  -->
<div class="instagram-box">
    <div class="main-instagram owl-carousel owl-theme">
        @foreach($media as $post)
        <div class="item">
            <div class="ins-inner-box">
                <img src="{{ $post['imageThumbnailUrl'] }}" alt="" />
                <div class="hov-in">
                    <a href="{{ $post['link'] }}" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Instagram Feed  -->
@endif
@endisset
```

Here is the code that is added after running the website That is added by JavaScript:

```
<div class="instagram-box">
        <div class="main-instagram owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">    
        <div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-702px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 1560px;"><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-06.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-07.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-08.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-09.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-05.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-01.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-02.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-03.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-04.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-05.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-06.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-07.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-08.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-09.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-05.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-01.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-02.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-03.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-04.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 78px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="ins-inner-box">
                    <img src="images/instagram-img-05.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="hov-in">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div></div><div class="owl-nav"><button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button><button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button></div><div class="owl-dots disabled"></div></div>
    </div>
```

**HOWEVER** After I added the font code, even without referencing any file just calling the function `@font-face {}` Destroyed the Whole instagram section But worked PERFECTLY on Every things else here is the picture: [image: Wrong Picture]

After Inspect element it appears that each item is taking the whole width 100% of the given bootstrap container and it is stacking them vertically without showing the instagram pictures.

**PS:** Here is the repo of the theme the changes are in `css/styles.css` please check all [repo](https://github.com/hilal-najem3/carousel-css-js/tree/main):

How Can I fix that??

Thank you :)

Much Apprectiated

Comment: Looks like this is a dead end :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the `@font-face` from `style.css` file and moving it to a different file fixed the issue